# How to save remote ipynb files easily in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have just started using vs code, so this may be a question with a very obvious answer.

This is my setup:

I have a large server with computation resources to run my models. Previously I would use jupyter notebooks to connect to it and run my long running code. If I needed to save the file, a simple save button would save the changes in the remote.

Now I want to switch to vscode. It has a useful remote-ssh extension that allows it to connect to a remote server and from my viewpoint, it is almost as if I am coding locally.

vscode also has the ability to run jupyter notebooks. Once you start your notebook server, you can simply type it in and it will use the jupyter notebooks virtual environment for the code.

The problem comes when I want to save a remote jupyter notebook (i.e. the notebook itself is present on the server).

I am presented with this menu:

[image]

I know it is possible to navigate all the way to the directory where this file is present, and then hit okay, but I think this can be a source of error, especially if there are multiple .ipynb files that I am running. Also, when I do choose the same file using this method, I have to deal with the 'file already exists, are you sure you want to overwrite?'. I dont think I am using this feature the way it is intended to. How do I simply save an ipynb file just like I save other files on a remote ssh server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in VS code. It only affects ipynb files that are are named Untitled.ipynb.

When I hit save on an ipynb file with any other name, it saves directly, as I would expect it to.